# how to get the value of href in table row?

Tags: php, html, mysql

My first work is here.
They search for the name and display the table of such names.
I'm using another text field to get the ID number of applicants to display their profile.
Now, I want to do it by just clicking their ID number which is on the table row.
I tried this code but seems it doesn't work.

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("select * from applicant_data")
   or die('Error in query : $sql. ' .mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) 
{            

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

?>                  
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff"><form method="post" action="psp_view_profile.php" name="submit" >
<?php echo '<a href="psp_view_profile.php?$no="> ' . $row['id'] . '</a>'?></td></form>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff"><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff"><?php echo $row['firstname']; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff"><?php echo $row['middlename']; ?></td>

<?php
}
}
?>
```

And this one is from psp_view_profile.php

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$no = $_POST['no'];
    $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM applicant_data WHERE id='$no'");

    while($_GET = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){

    $Date = $_GET["datapply"];
    $FirstName = $_GET["firstname"];
    $MiddleName = $_GET["middlename"];
    $LastName = $_GET["lastname"];
    $RStreet = $_GET['res_st'];
    $RBarangay = $_GET['barangay'];
 //and so on...
```

Comment: `while($_GET`? Believe me, you don't want to use that. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Comment: you need to put the id in the link, as well as just the text you click on

Comment: @Fred-ii- wow, i have never seen any done do that before -it would work but still

Comment: @Dagon I'm under the impression it's going to cause havoc.

Comment: @Dagon plus, there's nothing to "link" anything; they're using HTML table codes as references. cargo cult programming, as Marc B would call it lol

Comment: and `$no = $_POST['no'];` should be `$_GET` its all odd

Comment: @Dagon I guess we can't really hack it till we've tried it. Personally, I like mine with a bit of milk. and they said *once you've had it black, you'll never go back* - blech... nah, I like my cappuccino, thank you.

Comment: phantom  `<form> .. </form>` found

Comment: on top of tagging as js and jquery, why?

Comment: 2 up votes, he must have friends

Comment: haha, And now its reversed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `$` sign before `no` in this line:

```
<?php echo '<a href="psp_view_profile.php?no="> ' . $row['id'] . '</a>'?></td></form>
```

As well - if a user clicks on a link it becomes a GET request, so in the psp_view_profile.php query `$_GET` to param value, like so

```
$no = $_GET['no'];
```

UPDATE:

Missed in the original answer - please concatenate actual id value to the URL, here is an example:

```
<?php echo '<a href="psp_view_profile.php?no=' . $row['id'] . '"> ' . $row['id'] . '</a>'?></td></form>
```

Comment: still not quite right

Comment: still not working...